# REST request for creating a new DataCategoryGroup or DataCategory

Tags: metadata-api, rest, knowledge, data-category, categories

I can't find any documentation on creating a new DataCategoryGroup or DataCategory object from the REST API. I can read them, and link them to knowledge articles, but I can't see to find anything about creating new groups or categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get this working but it's not what I would call a "RESTful" solution. The only way to create new DataCategoryGroups and DataCategories is through the Metadata API. The Metadata API operates by uploading zipped file structures of XML.

The REST endpoint for metadata is described here:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm

The metadata file for DataCategoryGroups that needs uploaded in the zip file is described here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.knowledge_dev.meta/knowledge_dev/meta_datacategorygroup.htm

Note:On writing this there were a few typos in the sample XML file, the most frustrating was the space after "KnowledgeArticleVersion" in the "<object>" tag. Took me a bit to find it and causes the operation to fail with:
"There is no entity matching KnowledgeArticleVersion"

There are no examples of what the package.xml should look like for this call with a DataCategoryGroup so I am including it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>DataCategoryGroup</name>
    </types>
    <version>49.0</version>
</Package>
```